# How to make dynamic events : onCreate and onChange in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm having trouble creating event for a dynamic Combobox, when is created.

When I click button, at this moment create dynamic panel in scrollboxes, labels,edit and button to destroy panel.

I would add events onCreate and onChange to first combobox.
First combobox will be have first values (categories), second - subcategories (when first will be chosen).

How to make working events onCreate and onChange?

Code:

```
procedure TfrmGenerateExam.aAnulujExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ModalResult := mrCancel;
end;

procedure TfrmGenerateExam.aDodajNoweSzczegolyExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  dynPanel: TPanel;
  dyncbKategoria: TComboBox;
  dyncbPodkategoria: TComboBox;
begin
  dynPanel := TPanel.Create(ScrollBox);
  try
    with dynPanel do
    begin
     {Panel properties} 
   end;
    dyncbKategoria := TComboBox.Create(dynPanel);
    with dyncbKategoria do
    begin
      Parent := dynPanel;
      Top := 29;
      Left := 5;
      Width := 245;
      Height := 21;
      OnCreate := setKategoria;
      OnChange := setPodkategoria;
    end;
    end;
    Panel.Add(dynPanel);
    cbKategoria.Add(dyncbKategoria);
    cbPodkategoria.Add(dyncbPodkategoria);
  except
    dynPanel.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Code onCreate {dosent work add items}:

```
procedure TfrmGenerateExam.setKategoria(Sender: TObject);
var
firstComboBox : TComboBox;
begin
 with Query do begin
   SQL.Text :={SQL script}
    Open;
    try
      while not Eof do
      begin
        first.Items.Add(Fields[0].AsString);
        Next;
      end;
    finally
      Close;
    end;
 end;
```

Code onChange  {dosent work add items}:

```
procedure TfrmGenerateExam.setPodKategoria(Sender: TObject);
var
firstComboBox : TComboBox;
secondComboBox : TComboBox;
begin
 with Query do begin
   SQL.Text :={SQL script using value from first combobox}
    Open;
    try
      while not Eof do
      begin
        secondComboBox.Items.Add(Fields[0].AsString);
        Next;
      end;
    finally
      Close;
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: I can't work out what your question is. Can you edit to improve the focus of the question.

Comment: This is WAY too much code to sift through. Please edit your question to replace the code with a [mcve] (emphasis on “minimum”) demonstrating the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay, I edited

Comment: @Paweł it is still too much code. Do you not understand the concept of “minimum”? Get rid of all the code that is not relevant to the question. Post only the bare minimum amount of code needed to get your point across. What you have shown can be stripped down much further. If you can’t strip down your actual code, make a separate example program.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, now i think is really minimum code

Comment: You should also remove all the SQL. It's unnecessary and makes the code execution unreproducible because we don't have your database.

Comment: Even with the SQL removed, the question itself is not very clear. What EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish, and what EXACTLY is the problem you are having with that? Please clarify the issue. Controls don’t have OnCreate events, only Forms do. And you already know how to assign an OnChange event handler. It seems to me you don’t know how to identify WHICH ComboBox is changed (hint, look at the Sender parameter), or WHICH 2nd ComboBox to update (hint, use the TComboBox.Tag property to link the 2 TComboBox controls together).

Comment: Are you pnieradko using a new username?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, vaules dont want to add to items to the first and second combobox

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, because there is limit questions

Comment: @Paweł “*vaules dont want to add to items to the first and second combobox*” - I don’t understand what you are trying to explain, please edit your question to clarify the actual problem. “*yes, because there is limit questions*”- it is frowned upon on this site to create multiple accounts to ask multiple questions. Limits exist for a reason, please respect them, or you are likely to not get any help at all if you are caught breaking the rules.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wolud add values to first combobox when this first is create. When I want change value in first combobox after create, it should be add new values to second combobox

Comment: @Paweł “*I wolud add values to first combobox when this first is create*” - you already know how to do that. You deleted that code from your original question. There is no `OnCreate` event for `TComboBox`, simply run the desired code after calling `Create()`. “*When I want change value in first combobox after create, it should be add new values to second combobox*” - I already told you what to look at for that. Did you even try what I suggested yet?

Comment: @Paweł I have added an answer for you now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `OnCreate` event for `TComboBox` (or any other control). Just run the desired code immediately after creating the control.  As for updating the 2nd ComboBox, use the `OnChange` event’s `Sender` parameter to know which ComboBox is being changed. You can use its `Tag` property to link it to the 2nd ComboBox.

```
procedure TfrmGenerateExam.aDodajNoweSzczegolyExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  dynPanel: TPanel;
  dyncbKategoria: TComboBox;
  dyncbPodkategoria: TComboBox;
begin
  dynPanel := TPanel.Create(ScrollBox);
  try
    with dynPanel do
    begin
     {Panel properties} 
    end;

    dyncbKategoria := TComboBox.Create(dynPanel);
    with dyncbKategoria do
    begin
      Parent := dynPanel;
      Top := 29;
      Left := 5;
      Width := 245;
      Height := 21;
    end;

    dyncbPodKategoria := TComboBox.Create(dynPanel);
    with dyncbPodKategoria do
    begin
      Parent := dynPanel;
      {ComboBox properties}
    end;

    dyncbKategoria.Items.BeginUpdate;
    try
      with Query do
      begin
        SQL.Text := {SQL script}
        Open;
        try
          while not Eof do
          begin
            dyncbKategoria.Items.Add(Fields[0].AsString);
            Next;
          end;
        finally
          Close;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      dyncbKategoria.Items.EndUpdate;
    end;

    dyncbKategoria.Tag := NativeInt(dyncbPodkategoria);
    dyncbKategoria.OnChange := setPodkategoria;

    Panel.Add(dynPanel);
    cbKategoria.Add(dyncbKategoria);
    cbPodkategoria.Add(dyncbPodkategoria);
  except
    dynPanel.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmGenerateExam.setPodKategoria(Sender: TObject);
var
  firstComboBox : TComboBox;
  secondComboBox : TComboBox;
begin
  firstComboBox := TComboBox(Sender);
  secondComboBox := TComboBox(firstComboBox.Tag);
  secondComboBox.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    secondComboBox.Items.Clear;
    with Query do
    begin
      SQL.Text := {SQL script using value from first combobox}
      Open;
      try
        while not Eof do
        begin
          secondComboBox.Items.Add(Fields[0].AsString);
          Next;
        end;
      finally
        Close;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    secondComboBox.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hint: "With" statement should be avoided. It leads to future bugs and is difficult to debug.